# Function to convert Hex to Oct in haskell

Tags: haskell, hex, octal

I have to convert any Hex Number to an Oct number.
On another post I saw this code

```
main = do
    octStr <- getLine
    let
        val :: Integer
        (val,_):_ = readOct octStr
        hexStr = showHex val ""
    putStrLn hexStr
```

for Oct to Hex, but I dont understand the `readOct` function..

Can anyone explain that to me or help me otherwise?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `readOct` is just a simple function, this is the function that actually *does* the work, all the rest is more reading input and printing output. The file thus contains/imports, somewhere else a `readOct` function.

Comment: Do I just have to add ```readOct = "0644" ``` for example in the first line of that code and then the program converts that number into a Hexadecimal number?

Comment: no, `readOct` is a *function* that takes a string and returns a `Integer`. But nevertheless, the code fragment is not really functional programming. This looks more like a person converting an imperative program to Haskell.

Comment: To be fair, I don't really understand `readOct` either, based on its usage. Rather than something simple like `String -> Integer`, the type appears to be `String -> [(Integer, ?)]` for some unknown type `?`.

Answer (score 1):

`readOct` has a weird type because it's meant to be efficiently chained with other `ReadS` parsers. Here's a helper function to make it simple to use functions like that:

```
runReadS :: ReadS a -> String -> Maybe a
runReadS f s = case f s of
    [(x, "")] -> Just x
    _ -> Nothing
```

If there's exactly one valid parse and it uses the entire input, then that function returns `Just` the result of the parse. Otherwise (if there was no parse at all, if there were multiple ambiguous parses, or if there were unparsed bits of the string left over), it returns `Nothing`. You can then use that function in a more simple way in your code like this:

```
import Numeric

main = do
    octStr <- getLine
    case runReadS readOct octStr of
        Nothing -> putStrLn $ octStr ++ " is not valid octal!"
        Just val -> putStrLn $ octStr ++ " in octal is " ++ showHex val " in hexadecimal."
```

The `showHex` function is similarly weird-looking. Instead of returning some string `str`, it returns effectively `str ++`, to allow for efficient chaining.